# XML parsing ampersand in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML document I'm parsing in Scala, a clip of which might look like this:

```
<my_url>
http://whatever.com/somestuff?id=123&amp;sub=http%3A%2F%2Fanother.com%22
</my_url>
```

I'm parsing the text by matching on EvText events like this:

```
case EvText(text) =>
    fieldText = text.toString
```

My problem is that I'm getting two EvText events for the url above.  One for this part:

```
  http://whatever.com/somestuff?id=123
```

and another for this part:

```
  sub=http%3A%2F%2Fanother.com%22
```

The ampersand is lost.  Is there a way to detect/handle this so I can get the unified URL string I need?  I don't/can't know the type of my_url (i.e. I don't know there's a URL in that field).

Comment: This looks kind of like a duplicate—does my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16592448/334519) help?

Comment: Yes, thats it, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLEventReader generates two EvText events for single tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591404/xmleventreader-generates-two-evtext-events-for-single-tag)